# Tensor flow - Mac GPU installation

Tags: tensorflow

After I run a python3 script I get the following statements and do not know where the 3 errors are coming from. I am using cudnn v5.0 but obviously I have gone wrong somewhere along the installation pipeline. Any help would be fantastic.

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.1.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.dylib locally
number of elements at final reshape = %d. 61440
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:892] OS X does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GT 750M
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.9255
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 2.00GiB
Free memory: 1.28GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:838] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 750M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:354] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:361] error retrieving driver version: Invalid argument: expected %d.%d or %d.%d.%d form for driver version; got ""
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:321] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:457] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: you could try disabling SIP (system integrity protection)

Comment: Did that help or no?

Comment: I didn't try it, are you sure its a good idea to disable SIP? Just from having read a little about it.

Comment: when I installed my TensorFlow GPU, disabling SIP was a requirement (ie, when my SIP reverted to default, TF GPU stopped working. I turned it off again, it started working again)

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed the wrong cuDNN!

I had the same probablem and was able to fix mine by replacing my cuDNN with one compatiable:

[image]

Comment: I think I have installed multiple cudnn versions now. What's the best way to uninstall other versions? Do I just rm the header and lib files ?

Comment: Yep! Just rm the files you added in the installation step and you should be good to go.